# How to get 1 row from every group sql

Tags: sql, oracle

My current query from a table is giving me something like this

```
C1 | C2 | C3 | C4
xx | cc | ff | i1
xx | dd | kk | i2
yy | oo | tt | i3
zz | uu | ll | i4
zz | jj | ee | i5
```

All the 'i's are integers

I am grouping by C1, C2, C3

I want to to get only one row for every distinct C1 value corresponding to highest C4 value

Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

For this, you want analytic functions.  The function `row_number()` does what you want:

```
select c1, c2, c3, c4
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by c1 order by c4 desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple with co-related subqs:

```
select C1,C2,C3,C4 from table tb where c4 in 
(select max(C4) from table where C1=tb.C1 )
```

Edit:

After Conrad's comment, for the following set of data:

```
c1      c2      c3      c4
 1      2        3       4
 1      3        4       4
```

This query will return both rows.

I am still not sure if it is required or not, for me it looks like we should return 2 rows for this data, as we are not able to distinguish between two and both rows are fulfilling the requirements.

It's something like we want to know in which subject a student got highest marks. If he got 92 both in Maths and English, we should return both rows.

Comment: Unless C4 is guaranteed to be unique more than one row can come back for a given group.